# Lightbox Plugin is not working with Custom Developing theme

Tags: php, wordpress, lightbox

I am developing Custom wordpress theme and already I've deleted default themes came under wordpress.

However, I've installed lightbox plugin for display my gallery images in a lightbox. But it isn't working.

Here is my code:

**page-gallery.php**

```
get_header(); ?>


 <section class="content pull-left width-wide clear-both">
            <div class="wrap">
                <!-- Inside Content -->
                <div class="inside-content inside-page pull-left width-wide clear-both">

                    <!-- page header -->
                    <div class="page-header pull-left width-wide">
                        <!-- Title -->
                        <h1>Gallery</h1><!-- Title -->

                        <!-- Breadcrumb -->
                    <ul class="_bread">
                    <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/wordpress/" title="Home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Gallery" class="active">Gallery</a></li>
            </ul>
<!-- Breadcrumb -->  
                    </div><!-- // page header -->

                    <!-- Gallery -->
                    <div class="gallery pull-left width-wide">
                        <!-- Menu -->
                        <div class="cat-menu pull-right padding-right-20">
                            <!--Categories : -->

                         <!-- <a href="#showall" title="Show All" class="active">Show All</a>
                                                        <a href="#Category1" title="Category 1 " >Category 1 </a>
                                                        <a href="#Category2" title="Category 2" >Category 2</a>
                                                        <a href="#Category3" title="Category 3" >Category 3</a> -->

                        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#showall">Show All</a></li>
                                <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#Category1">Category 1</a></li>
                                <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#Category2">Category 2</a></li>
                                <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#Category3">Category 3</a></li>
                        </ul> 
                        </div><!-- // Menu -->

                        <!-- Gallery Items -->

                <div class="gallery-items pull-left width-wide">

                <div class="tab-content">
                        <div id="showall" class="tab-pane fade in active">

                            <?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>

                            <?php endwhile; 
                                else: 
                                    echo "Content not found";
                                 endif; 
                            wp_reset_postdata();?>  

                        </div>   

                         <div id="Category1" class="tab-pane">

                            <?php
                                $my_page_id = 766; //your page or post ID
                                $my_page = get_post($my_page_id); //retrieves the page via the ID
                                $content = $my_page->post_content; //gets the unfiltered page content
                                $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); //cleanup content
                                $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content); //cleanup content
                                $title = $my_page->post_title; //retrieves page title and sets the variable
                                ?>

                                <?php
                                echo $content; //show page content
                            ?>


                    </div>

                         <div id="Category2" class="tab-pane">

                            <?php
                                $my_page_id = 769; //your page or post ID
                                $my_page = get_post($my_page_id); //retrieves the page via the ID
                                $content = $my_page->post_content; //gets the unfiltered page content
                                $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); //cleanup content
                                $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content); //cleanup content
                                $title = $my_page->post_title; //retrieves page title and sets the variable
                                ?>

                                <?php
                                echo $content; //show page content
                            ?>

                    </div>



                         <div id="Category3" class="tab-pane">

                            <?php
                                $my_page_id = 772; //your page or post ID
                                $my_page = get_post($my_page_id); //retrieves the page via the ID
                                $content = $my_page->post_content; //gets the unfiltered page content
                                $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); //cleanup content
                                $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content); //cleanup content
                                $title = $my_page->post_title; //retrieves page title and sets the variable
                                ?>

                                <?php
                                echo $content; //show page content
                            ?>

                         </div>

                     </div>
                        </div><!-- // Gallery Items -->
                    </div><!-- // Gallery -->

                </div><!-- Inside Content -->
            </div>
        </section><!-- // Content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I've already added relavent bootstrap and jquery min links to header.php

I've created gallery page under 3 dynamic pills. Active one was retrieve images from main gallery page through wordpress loop and other 3 pills retreive images from post. (FYI only)

Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you mention which lightbox plugin you used? I'm sure there must be missing data attributes to related gallery elements.

Comment: Its "Simple Lightbox"

Comment: if you are using this - https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
your code looks missing some of data attributes.

Comment: @ChamiM Hi thanks for your prompt response. Actually I am new to wordpress development. Can you tell the missing part of my code is? Or.. My actual requirement is to apply a light box a code without a plugin. The thing is I don't understand how to apply lightbox code to my current wordpress loop (custermize the code which can apply). Can you help me with that.

Comment: Seems like you missed [ data-lightbox=" " ] from your gallery item. I'm sure the documentation is explain this very well.  Read it carefully and try to create it in static HTML file. then apply it to the wordpress site. It will be easier.

Comment: Hi, You know where to apply data-lightbox please...?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use [Responsive Lightbox & Gallery](https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-lightbox/) plugin?? This could help you to achieve the lightbox on website as you need it. It will add attributes to image dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I'll help you with lightbox. But you need to add a loop for image gallery in order to display the relevant image which you click.

Please use advance custom field. Also I created the lightbox using [w3school lightbox](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp)

**gallery.php**

```
<?php $images = get_field('gallery');
                        if( $images ): ?>

                                <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                                    <div class="gallery_content_wrapper"> 

                                            <div class="item col-md-4">
                                                <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"  width="344" height="215" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="cursor">
                                            </div>

                                    <?php if ( function_exists('slb_activate') ){
                                    $content = slb_activate($content);
                                    }
                                    echo $content; ?>

                            <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                                <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
                                <div class="modal-content">

                                <div class="mySlides">
                                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
                                </div>

                                 <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
                            </div>
                            </div>



                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
```

**custom.css**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100000000;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  /*text-align: center;*/
}

.mySlides{
  text-align: center;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 1;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

footer{
  position: sticky;
}
```

**custom.js**

```
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

Hope you'll find the answer from this.